# Access value entered in Apex:input in vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to add value entered in a longtext field(comments__c) into existing long text field (all_comments__c) on Lead. But comments value is coming as null in all_comments__c field. Can anyone tell me how do i pass value entered in apex:input field of comments__c in extension class.

my vf page:-

```
<apex:page standardController="lead" extensions="UpdateInfoExt" sidebar="false" title="Update Form" standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" >
 <apex:form >
   <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <table style="width:100%">
     <tr> 
     <td><b><apex:outputLabel value="Email" style="float:right"></apex:outputLabel></b></td>
     <td><apex:inputField value="{!lead.email}" style="font-size:90%;width:70%;margin-left:5%"/></td> 
     </tr> 
     <tr> 
     <td><b><apex:outputLabel value="Company" style="float:right"></apex:outputLabel></b></td>
     <td><apex:inputField value="{!lead.Company}" style="font-size:90%;width:70%;margin-left:5%"/></td> 
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><b><apex:outputLabel value="Comments" style="float:right"></apex:outputLabel></b></td>
     <td><apex:inputField value="{!lead.Comments__c}" style="font-size:90%;width:70%;margin-left:5%"/></td>
     </tr> 
    </table>
    <br/><br/>
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <apex:commandButton value="Save Changes" action="{!savechanges}" style="width:20%; background-color:white" />
    </div>
   </apex:pageBlock>
   <br/>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

And extension class:-

```
public class UpdateInfoExt{
    private ApexPages.StandardController controller;
    public Lead ldqueried;
    public UpdateInfoExt(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }
    public pagereference savechanges(){  
        controller.save(); 

        ldqueried = [select id, all_comments__c, Comments__c from Lead where id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') limit 1];
        Lead ld = new Lead();
        ld.all_comments__c = ldqueried.all_comments__c +' [comments from Stay in Touch form: '+ ld.Comments__c+']';
        ld.Comments__c = '';
        ld.id = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        update ld;   
    }
```

}

Comment: You are not querying and assigning any value to  all_comments__c. Try         ldqueried = [select id, Lead_Notes__c, all_comments__c, Comments__c from Lead where id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') limit 1];                                               ldqueried.all_comments__c = ldqueried.Comments__c;                                                  update ldqueried;

Comment: apologies for the typo.....I have corrected the question. i get all_comments__c value correctly; problem is in value of apex:input of comments__c entered in vf page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a standard controller, the page's record is bound to the Standard Controller's record. Your code should look more like this:

```
public class UpdateInfoExt{
    private ApexPages.StandardController controller;
    public UpdateInfoExt(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }
    public pagereference savechanges(){  
        controller.save(); 
        Lead record = (Lead)controller.getRecord();
        Lead comments = [SELECT All_Comments__c FROM Lead WHERE Id = :record.Id];
        record.all_comments__c = comments.all_comments__c +' [comments from Stay in Touch form: '+ record.Comments__c+']';
        record.Comments__c = '';
        controller.save();
    }
}
```